# Re-Writing URL with .htaccess don't works with multiple re-writes dynamic or static

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have trouble in making fancy URLs with `.htaccess`.

I'm saving titles in database like "name-of-a-title" but problems start when I try to access it from URL, it doesn't show me the CSS, only the content.

This URL for blog works like:

```
http://example.com/blog?title=page-title
```

and I need a URL like this

```
http://example.com/blog/post-title
```

Here is my file, I'm a beginner.

```
<files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog$ blog.php
RewriteRule ^blog/$ blog.php
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]*)$ /blog?title=$1 [L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]*)$ category.php?$1 [L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # To externally redirect /dir/abc.php to /dir/abc
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my-webiste.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.my-website.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Comment: the 3rd rule must be more precise `RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]+)$ /blog.php?title=$1 [L]`. Remove extra `RewriteEngine On`s.

Comment: still i am not getting header or footer properly

Comment: you can open this link   http://www.softcrayons.com/blog/benifits-of-seo

Comment: when u open softcrayons.com/blog then working fine

Comment: and when i type this http://www.softcrayons.com/blog?title=benifits-of-seo then i will get properly header or footer

Comment: `<link href="css/bootstrap.css"` must be `<link href="/css/bootstrap.css"` with a front slash, that means a relative path to root.

Comment: @arifkhan SuperDuperApps's answer would seem to be correct. You have a problem with relative URLs in your application. See also my answer to this question over on the Pro Webmasters stack: [.htaccess rewrite URL leads to missing CSS](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86450/htaccess-rewrite-url-leads-to-missing-css)

Comment: same problen i face

Comment: noting happen sir

Comment: specify the `<base href="//www.your_site.com/" />` or maybe `<base href="/" />` inside the `<head>` tags.

Comment: can u check my code please

Comment: i know you can resolve my problem please check my project its my humble request sir

Comment: sir please save my job

Answer (score 1):

You just need to update your HTML so it uses absolute links to reference the CSS, images etc. With your fancy URLs the browser is now starting from `/blog/` instead of root to find them.

Comment: i didn't understand can message me on skype 00786arif@gmail.com  please save my job

Comment: please give me your skype name then i will show you my project

Comment: Search Google for the difference between absolute and relative URLs, read all you need to about it until you understand. Then apply what you've learned to use absolute URLs for your CSS and images. Hey presto! You saved your own job.

Comment: once you check my project then u understand what problem i faced

Comment: sir i am begginer  so i didn't get please help me once you check my project please save my job

Comment: when i  type my url http://localhost/blog?title=hello-everyone then i got header or footer and also contant data thats working fine  but when i click on blog menu then i got every thing but when i click any blog title then i will

Comment: get like this http://localhost/blog/hello-everyone that url fine but i am not getting header or footer properly but content getting fine

Comment: so how get my heder or footer properly please tell me

Comment: Have you learned what relative and absolute URLs are? I will not be checking your project on Skype. If you want me to check your project on Skype, you will need to pay me by the hour for that. This is not a free service for any assistance you require. Try being grateful for the help that has already been offered, give proper answers to that, and stop complaining about your job, it is your problem, not mine.